# Explanation of two integral equations and implementation

Tags: matlab, integral

I have a problem with these two equations showing in the pictures.

[image: Equation one]

[image: Equation two]

1. I have two vectors represented the C(m) and S(m) in the two equations. I am trying to implement these equations in Matlab. Instead of doing a continuous integral operation, I think I should do the summation. For example, the first equation

   A1 = sqrt(sum(C.^2));

Am I right? Also, I am not sure how to implement equation two that contains a ||dM||. Please help.

2. What are the mathematical meaning of these two equations? I think the first one may related to the 'sum of squares', if C(m) is a vector then this equation will measure the total variance of the random variable in vector C or some kind of average of vector C? What about the second one?

Thanks very much for your help!
A.

Comment: as @Dennis suggests the mathematical focus of this question would be better at math.stackexchange or whichever field is appropriate. Leaving the "how do I do numerical integration on matlab" question here.

Answer (score 2):

In MATLAB there are typically two different ways to do an integration.

1. For people who have access to the symbolic toolbox, algebraic integration is an option. If this is the case for you, I would look into `help int` and see which inputs you need.
2. For the rest, numerical integration is available, this basically means that you just calculate a function on a lot of points and then take the mean of the function values in these points.

For the mathematical meaning some more context would be helpful, and you may want to ask this question at math.stackexchange.com or on the site of whatever field you are in. (stats, physics?)